# Who impersonated the Father in death bed in the movie Inception?

Tags: inception

There were seven people on the plane in *Inception*: Cobb, Arthur, Saito, Ariadne, Eames, Yusuf  and Robert Fischer. They all went into a road rage in the first level of the dream, and on the second level, leaving Yusuf behind, who was driving the van, and in charge of waking them back up to the first level, the rest entered the dream.

On the 3rd level, they were in a heavily guarded snow-covered hill-top compound, leaving Arthur behind in the second level. Five of them enter, namely, Cobb, Saito, Ariadne, Eames and Robert Fischer, where Saito and Fischer die and  Cobb and Ariadne enter the fourth level to bring them back, leaving Eames in charge.

Ariadne finds and sends Fischer back. On the 3rd level of dream, after Fischer's revival, only two (Eames and Fischer) were left. Fischer enters in a room with his Father's deathbed who (the Father) is supposed to plant the idea. Who is the father supposed to be impersonated by? It can't be someone from the team since there was no one left to do that. Then who was the Father and how?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Wasn't the whole plan to let Fischer think he gives himself the idea? The father would then be a projection, or you might as well ask who was impersonating the hotel security.

Comment: This is very hard to follow, and I feel a large part of that is because you are listing the actors in brackets every time you mention the character names.  This is completely unnecessary.  Anyone answering is likely already familiar with the characters, and even if knowing the actors would help, mentioning it _every time_ you mention the character distracts from the flow of the text.  If you feel like you need to point out the actors for each character, I would suggest only doing it once, then using the character names only afterwords.

Comment: Yeah, @M.A.R. I totally expect the father was a projection.  The architect designed a hospital, so Fischer would fill it with a projection of his father - in much the same way that if you provide a safe, the mark will fill it with his/her secrets.

Comment: Also I agree - the question can be put much more simply than this.  It's a perfectly good question, but it could be stated in a few lines.  It doesn't need all the actors names or the whole sequence of levels stated.

Comment: @JMac: I have seen the movie, but i still prefer to see both character names as well as actor names. Now that the actor names are removed, i need to open a second list off-screen to keep the overview. Maybe having a list at the end of the question would be helpful instead of in-line brackets.

Comment: English names are not very familiar reference to remember the plot of a movie for the non-native English speaker instead it is easier to remember and understand the plot by visuals with the the actual actor's names (which is much more familiar) and then relate to the movie characters, it is the way I see it. For instance you people think about an Iranian movie plot.

Comment: Ok, watched two times more after this including plenty of times in past and yes they used "Don't think about Elephant" technique in a very subtle way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mechanism for how this works is explained by an earlier scene when Cobb is explaining to Ariadne what her role as Architect would be:

```
COBB
This is where you come in. You build the world of the dream.
We take the subject into that dream, and let him fill it with his 
subconscious

Build a bank vault or a jail, something secure, and the subject's
mind will fill it with information he's trying to protect.
```

Part of their plan (as detailed by Mr Nick's answer) is to convince Fischer that Browning is trying to undermine his father's wish that he break up their business empire.  They use Eames' forgery skills to impersonate Browning as part of this process.

However most 'people' in the world are projections of the dreamer's subconscious.

So they design the lowest (planned) layer of the dream to be a highly guarded hospital.  The idea here is that (like the bank-vault) that Robert Fischer will fill that hospital with projections that he closely associates with medical care or illness .... i.e. his father.

```
COBB
How are the mazes coming?

ARIADNE
Good. Each level relates to the part of the subject's subconscious
we're trying to access. I'm making the bottom level a hospital, so
that Fischer will bring his father there
```

Their plan is that the cathartic experience he dreams in that final hospital room will seal the business break-up plan in Robert's mind.  So even later when he comes to and realizes that it is all a dream, and perhaps doubts Browning's involvement, he may still go through with it.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, Fischer's father was a projection of Fischer's mind. When they first enter Fischer's mind, they wouldn't be able to convince Fischer's mind to turn away from Peter Browning and toward his father just by being themselves, so Eames impersonates Browning as part of a plan to make Fischer believe that Browning is betraying him. Then on the next level, we learn that it works when Fischer has this interaction with Browning (Who at this point is his projection, not Eames):

> FISCHER: Uncle Peter. What's going on?
>
> COBB: You said you were kidnapped
>   together?
>
> FISCHER: Not exactly, they already had him. They'd been torturing him...
>
> COBB: You saw them torture him?
>
> Fischer shakes his head. Looks at Browning. Thinking.
>
> FISCHER: The kidnappers are working for you.
>
> BROWNING: No, Robert-
>
> FISCHER: You're trying to get that safe open. To get the alternate will.
>
> Browning looks up at Fischer.
>
> BROWNING: Fischer Morrow's been my entire life. I can't let you destroy it.

The result of this shift is confirmed again, when Fischer's father's projection says he wants Fischer to go his own way, and they complete their mission. It's all a result of the team's influence on Fischer's mind and his perspective on his father.